# server returns empty json when requesting from python session

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a REST call to a network device using python session to apply a config change. When the config apply fails, call to CheckApplyTable should give me the cause of apply failure.
When making a direct call to the device, I get a JSON response like below

```
 {
    "CheckApplyTable":[{
    "Index": 1,
    "StringVal": "Error: Apply not done.  ERROR TEXT"
    }]
 }
```

When making the same request using python, I get below response:

```
{
'CheckApplyTable': []
}
```

The CheckApplyTable key value is returned as empty list instead of the expected result.
Below is an excerpt from my code

```
header = {'Accept': 'text/html, application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
apply_url = 'https://' + server + '/config?action=apply'
apply_success_url = 'https://' + server + '/config/CheckApplyTable'
with requests.Session() as session:
   session.auth = auth
   session.verify = False
   session.headers = header                         
   session.post(apply_url)
   check_apply = session.get(apply_success_url)
   jcheck_apply = check_apply.json()
   print(jcheck_apply)
```

Please help me figure out what am I missing.

Comment: You are missing details about the device and its API.

Comment: While playing with postman, I found out that the url needs to be encoded (enabled by default on Postman). Now trying to find how to encode my url.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my own problem. The problem was timing. When I send the apply call, the error was not yet generated. I had to put in a while loop to check the status of apply. If the apply state is in progress, keep checking its status. If the apply state is failed, then make the CheckApplyTable call.